# Excel two-way list comparison summary

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am running a two-way comparison on a set of Excel lists to check if an ID in list 1 exists in list 2 (and vice versa).  Any IDs missing in list 2 are a `Dropout`.  Any new IDs added in list 2 are `New`.  Any IDs in both lists are `Returning`.

I tried using a combination of IF and VLOOKUP.

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(sheet1!A2,sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Dropout","Returning")`

The one-way comparison (checking for dropouts) is working.  I need a way to check for new students (comparison in the opposite direction).  How can I do this in the same summary column?

**Update #1:**

The values in columns B:C of the summary sheet are drawn from sheet1.  Those need a formula to intelligently select the correct data from the correct sheet.

**Update #2:**

Appears that a Visual Basic script might be a smoother way to settle this issue.  Any pointers on how to approach this?

Class 1 Attendance:

[image: list 1]

Class 2 Attendance:

[image: list 2]

Summary:

[image: summary]

Comment: so you have no problem getting the combined list, you just want the formula for column A on the summary sheet?

Comment: @scott need the formula that compares list 1 to 2 *and* list 2 to 1 and returns results in Summary.  Essentially, cannot figure out how to add the "New" state for new students

Comment: That's what I am asking, You want formulas to give the results in all three columns or do you manually have the correct values in column B:C on Summary.  Your question and formula are hinting at the fact that you only need the formula in column A, and already have the data in columns B:C.  I am trying to make sure any answer given answers the whole question and not just part.

Comment: @scott This is a good point.  I think I need a new formula for column B:C because this would draw from multiple sheets.

Comment: If that is the case, Your best approach is going to be vba.  Otherwise you will need some pretty long Array formulas to combine the lists automatically.

Comment: If you *really* want to avoid VBA, you could just copy the contents from Sheet 2 under Sheet 3 and remove duplicates. But I think that is more error-prone than simply using vba.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload a VBA example for this?  I think out of the options this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because:

```
Sub outpt()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, outarr As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim st As Boolean, nd As Boolean
Dim item As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Class 1
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Class 2
Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3") 'Summary

With ws1
    arr1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
With ws2
    arr2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
End With

For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
        dict.Add arr1(i, 1), arr1(i, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
        dict.Add arr2(i, 1), arr2(i, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

ReDim outarr(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 3) As Variant
j = 1
For Each item In dict.keys
    st = False
    nd = False
    For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
        If arr1(i, 1) = item Then
            st = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        If arr2(i, 1) = item Then
            nd = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    outarr(j, 2) = item
    outarr(j, 3) = dict(item)
    If st And nd Then
        outarr(j, 1) = "Returning"
    ElseIf st Then
        outarr(j, 1) = "Dropout"
    Else
        outarr(j, 1) = "New"
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next item
'Assumes titles already in row 1
ws3.Range("A2").Resize(dict.Count, 3).Value = outarr


End Sub
```

Creates:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome - much more ideal than the formula-based approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An easy trick could be to duplicate your data in this way:

Class 1 Class 2

Class 2 Class 1

and performing the VLOOKUP from column one to the second one will get you the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine the 2 formulas:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet3!B2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Dropout",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet3!B2,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)),"New","Returning"))
```

(Assuming that class 1 attendance is on Sheet1, class 2 attendance is on Sheet2, and the Summary is on Sheet 3)

[image: Result]

But personally I would prefer something more readable (like NIVeR's answer).

And of course, Scott Craner's proposal is even better.

Comment: Using this formula as-is puts "Dropout" in all the entries.  I modified it to `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(sheet2!B2,sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Returning",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(sheet1!B2,sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"New","Dropout"))`.  Still not quite there as it returns "Returning" every time

Comment: On which sheet is your class1 attendance table? And on which sheet is your class2 attendance table? And on which sheet is your summary table?

Comment: Class 1 sheet 1.  Class 2 sheet 2. Summary 3

Comment: In that case you should lookup the values from Sheet3. If they're not in Sheet2, they're dropouts. Otherwise, if they're not on Sheet1, they're new. Otherwise, they are returning.

Comment: But still it is a nested IF. Nested IFs are *always* dangerous and error-prone, especially within long formulas. I would go for Scott's answer, if I were you ...

Comment: The wrinkle in this is Sheet 3 *in theory* will generate its entries from sheets 1 and 2 rather than being automatically included. That way entries can be added to sheets 1 and 2 and automatically reflected on 3